# Java EE 6 how to implement a lock on model

Tags: java-ee-6

I have a simple Java EE application that can viewer/edited by multiple people. I now want to implement the following feature:
If a user has the application open, no other use is allowed to edit until the first user logs out of the application. If there is no activity from the user, log them out after 2 hours. (For example if the user locks the screen and leaves for the day).

What is the best way to implement both of these features? For locking, I was thinking of a column in the db that I set when a user opens the page. And unset it after they log out.

How do I implement the 2 hour timer? Can I use the Timer EJBs to do this? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you would like to have only one user of your app at the time. My proposition:

1. Create Singleton bean witch will hold lock state
2. When somebody opens application, create timer (might be in same singleton), witch will expire after two hours, and changes then lock state.
3. When user logs out, cancel timer.

If you will use database for holding a lock state, after server crash you will have to do cleanup, which is not required in above solution.